# Dynamically set the 'default' DB in Django Project

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, django-settings

I am using Postgres DB and I have two databases that I am using.

Consider this example as I have to make two version of the software. In one version there is the main DB used for real data and second DB for test version of the software for trainee person.

Now how do I change the default DB according to the logged in User.
P.S: I know I can use 'using(db_name)'. But I don't want that. I want to change the default DB in settings.py dynamically.

The puspose is to provide a test version to the client with a seperate DB.

Comment: I guess this will be seperate instances of the application running? One for live and one for test?

Comment: you can set db_name variable in settings.py by default andwhen you change db_name in settings, others will be effected event it is on the fly

Comment: @urbanespaceman no both of them will run on a single instance. That is what I want to not have a seperate maintenance for test version

Comment: @obayhan I do know this but I don't know how to go about this. I can handle the setting version with development running on the localhost and production on test version but how do I do this with based on different login

Comment: I think your problem is that you shouldn' tbe running the same project against a live and a test DB simultaneously. IMHO your requirement  is bad - logging into a test env should not give you access to prod data and vice versa. Too much risk!